# How to understand the following code in C?

Tags: c

I'm using the PCG Random Number Generation package,and can not understand the following code.

```
time(NULL) ^ (intptr_t)&printf
```

which is a argument for the function to generate the seed for randomization:

```
void pcg32_srandom(uint64_t seed, uint64_t seq)
```

In the main function, it will be used as follow:

```
 pcg32_srandom(time(NULL) ^ (intptr_t)&printf, 54u);
```

BTW I also want to ask why "54u" should be written in such way?

Comment: Maybe could you add some details about where you found that code? The 54u is for unsigned number, it's the same as (uint64_t)54. But, I don't understand the first argument...

Comment: Note: On select machines, `time(NULL)` may return a FP value and then `^` does not work.  Could use `(uint64_t)time(NULL) ...`

Comment: @chux thanks for your remind.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure how much you know about random number generators, but often a random number generator is initialized by passing a number to it called a "seed".  In this case, the seed is chosen to be the time returned by the [time function](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/time.html) XORed with the address of the `printf` function.  I think this is not a very good random seed, and I wouldn't trust it with any important cryptographic tasks.

In C, when you write `54u` it tells the compiler that you are writing an unsigned number.  The `u` is not actually needed in the code you posted.

Comment: Could you recommend a better way to give a random seed?

Comment: Yeah, look at what `/dev/urandom` does on Linux; it continuously gathers entropy from a lot of sources including the timing of input from human users.  But secure random number seeding is a pretty broad topic and I don't think I can give you a complete description of it here.

Comment: Thanks, I will take a look.

Answer (score 2):

Let's break it down...

```
/* original: pcg32_srandom(time(NULL) ^ (intptr_t)&printf, 54u); */
uint64_t a = time(NULL);
uint64_t b = (intptr_t)&printf;
uint64_t c = a ^ b;
uint64_t d = 54u;
printf("a=%llx\n", (unsigned long long) a); /* no guessing about length */ 
printf("b=%llx\n", (unsigned long long) b); /* (thank you @chux) */
printf("c=%llx\n", (unsigned long long) c);
printf("d=%llx\n", (unsigned long long) d);
pcg32_srandom( a ^ b, d);
```

So... the ^ is the bitwise **xor** operator (edit: I originally wrote **or**).
Adding the printf should help you trace what the code is doing.
Apparently the code is xor-ing together something from time with
the address of the printf function (which is clever, I haven't seen
that before).

The **u** on the 54u is probably the original author being cautious.
When doing bit manipulations usually you don't want signed numbers.
This has some background: http://soundsoftware.ac.uk/c-pitfall-unsigned

We can see the API for pcg32_srandom() here:
   http://www.pcg-random.org/using-pcg-c-basic.html

```
and these variants for the global RNG:
   void pcg32_srandom(uint64_t initstate, uint64_t initseq)
   uint32_t pcg32_random()
   uint32_t pcg32_boundedrand(uint32_t bound)
```

So it looks like they're trying to come up with a seed for
the random number generator "initstate" and, for some reason,
want to use 54u as the "initseq".

Comment: Could use `printf("a=%llx\n", (unsigned  long long) a);  /* no guessing about length */`